# View PDFs in web browser

Tags: 2010, security, configuration, pdf

When I go to view a PDF on the web, say a 1040 form at the IRS, when I open it it opens in my browser.  When I open a PDF file from my sharepoint 2010 instance, however, it prompts me to download the file, and does not put any icon on it to indicate it is a PDF.

Is there some setting to tell SP 2010 to treat PDFs properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First, to open the file in browser**, go to Central Admin -> Select Your Web Application --> Select General Settings -> Select "Permissive" under browser file handling (also read the notes explaining the setting) as shown below:
[image]

**For PDF icons**, you need to associate .pdf with an icon and upload the icon image to C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web server extensions\14\Template\Images

For complete description, see [Icons are not displayed for Adobe PDF documents that are listed in the search results when you search your portal site in SharePoint](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832809)

Comment: Tread Carefully.  There is a reason this is turned off by default.

PDF launched in the browser are run in the same session, so opening from SharePoint gives PDF access to your credentials you just passed on.  Becouse PDF's can contain JavaScript this opens you up to potential cross site scripting attacks via the client object model.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer of ashish, there is some naughty bug with PDF's, permissive browserfile handling and SharePoint (well, IIS 7.5). depending on the pdf plugin used, the file will not be opened in your browser. It has something to do with a byterange in the header which is too long for the plugin, if I recall it correctly. We opened a case at Microsoft premier for it, and, from what I hear, they and Adobe are working on a solution.

Too bad, i can't find a link now with the problem described.

check http://www.pdfsharepoint.com/sharepoint-2010-and-pdf-integration-series-part-1/ for more information on SharePoint and PDF's