# Windows 7, IE9, need to bypass "Open/Save/Cancel" prompt to force user to open

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, internet-explorer, windows-7

I have Windows 7 machines working off MOSS 2007, and now the Windows 7 forces you to use IE9, I am at a loss on how to force open the documents you click on in the SharePoint Library instead of having to use the prompt every time.
When we were using XP machines with IE8, this was not an issue, because the document would open directly after clicking on it.

I simply want to have the file in our sharepoint library open up directly after clicking on it, rather than clicking on it, then clicking on the subsequent prompt it gives you.

Our users are not happy with the extra click on every document the review.

So, PLEASE, help me.  There has to be a way to solve this problem without reverting back to XP SP3 with IE8.

Answer (score 3):

Check this thread and answer for that: [View PDFs in web browser](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15875/view-pdfs-in-web-browser/15876#15876)

Also consider the pros/cons for the approach (comments in the answer)